# Xubuntu 22.04 - mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, xubuntu, automount

I have installed Xubuntu in dual boot with Windows 8.1 on my laptop Acer aspire VN7.
All works pretty well but I have these messages after the post :

```
[   10.238730] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
[   21.300623] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCIO.GFXO.D
D02._BCL], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
[   21.300646] ACPI ERROR: Aborting method \_SB.PCIO.PEGO.PEGP.DD02._BCL due to
previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[   21.867936]
```

I don't know if it is related but I have enabled automount before login
of the Acer partition which is on disk C and
of the Data partition on the disk D
while Xubuntu is installed on a partition on the disk D.
I used the Disks application of Xubuntu to enable the automount.

Question : Is there something I have to do ?

Comment: It seems my question has been answered here : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1981622